# First-order derivative of a function with integration

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

Given this function
$$f(x)=(\arctan(x))^2 \int_{\sqrt3}^{x^2}\frac{e^{-t}\sqrt t}{\ln(t^2+t)}dt$$
Calculate $f^{'}(\sqrt3)$

Comment: My effort all leads to calculate the integration explicitly. Is there any way to do it? Or is there any indirect way to calculate the derivative?

Comment: Yes, the fundamental theorem of calculus states that if 

$$
f(x) = \int_0^x g(t) \ \mathrm{d}t,
$$

then

$f'(x) = g(x)$.

For your problem you'll need this (and the chain rule) and the product rule.

Comment: Yes, if I write $f(x)=(\arctan(x))^2\int g(t)dt$ then
$$f^{'}(x)=\frac{2\arctan(x)}{x^2+1}\int g(t)dt+(\arctan(x))^2.2xg(x^2)$$
The integral is still there

Comment: Good point. I guess you have to compute it.